# Use Jmeter to send similar load (same exact requests) on two different servers (at same time, or one after the other)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Any ideas how to go about it. I don't want to run two different instances of Jmeter. I want to analyze the performance of a system before and after a fix.

So there are two options from a conceptual point of view:

- record the requests and replay them (and send them to before and after systems);
- multiplex the requests (and send them to two environments).

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) element in JMeter is designed to run multiple actions within the same test plan.

Once you have established the basic test you want to execute on the first server, right click and 'Duplicate' that thread group within the JMeter GUI.  Edit the Samplers of the newly created group for the second server.

If the test plan settings does not have the 'Run Thread Groups consecutively' box checked, these thread groups will execute at the same time against 2 different targets.

If you want your listeners to report the activity of both Thread Groups, then ensure they are the 'child' of the Test Plan and not the Thread Groups.

Answer (score 0):

Running 2 tests seems simpler to me as otherwise how will you make difference between samplers that hit old and new ? Unless you adapt plan so more work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

Use the -J property of jmeter-

Something like below:

> declare -a arr=("web01.example.com" "web02.example.com" "web03.example.com")
>
> for i in "${arr[@]}"
>
> do
>
> jmeter -n -t PostRequest.jmx -JWEB_SERVER=$i

Use

> ${__P(WEB_SERVER)}

in

stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${__P(WEB_SERVER)} <-in place of your Server.